# correct comment code for apostrophe s situation

Tags: c#, comments, apostrophe

Just curious how you would comment this line of code:

```
string customerNm = customerNm.EndsWith("s") ? customerNm+= "'" : customerNm+="'s";
```

Comment: I hope you know for sure that your application is never, ever going to be localized into any language other than English...

Comment: That may be true. But client does not care right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it into its own function, and name the function appropriately. That should be clear enough. (And you can test it more easily, too!)

```
string makePossessive(string customerName) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Though am on fan of one-line functions, I see the reasoning. Thanks

Comment: I'll agree with you, one-line functions can be odd. However, some people also don't prefer the conditional operator because it can make things less readable. If you expanded your statement out into an if/else, it wouldn't be a one-liner anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I would not necessarily comment it at all. It's clear enough as-is.

If you do comment it, you should explain *why* you do it the way you do.

E.g.:

```
/* Don't add "'s" for names ending on "s" 
  (request by Important Customer in June 1978) */
```

Comment: All comments, other than those for a public API, should answer the "why" question. I can read the code to find out what you did, but I want to know why you did it this way, or even did it at all.

Answer (score 3):

I would comment it with "not working". Because you access 'customerNm' before you assign to it.

(You use "customerNm+=..." which means: create a new string instance as a concatenation of the old instance [which isn't assigned yet] and ...).

This shouldn't even get compiled.

I think what you mean is:

```
customerNm += customerNm.EndsWith("s") ? "'" : "'s";
```

where customerNm is a string already assigned to once before.

Answer (score 2):

Not the question you're asking, but it looks like your code violates [grammar rules](http://www.uhv.edu/ac/grammar/pdf/apostrophes.pdf).

A name should not be treated like a plural noun just because it ends in 's'.  For instance, if James has a dog, it's James's dog, not James' dog.  However, if two life partners named Mike have a dog, it's both Mikes' dog.

Exception:  if a multisyllabic name ends in as "ess" or "ezz" sound, than it can be treated like a plural ending in 's'.  If Linus has a dog, it can be Linus' dog, although I believe Linus's is also acceptable.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link

Comment: LOL!  I corrected your grammar with poor grammar!  Last paragraph, "as" instead of "an" and "than" instead of "then".  I'm gonna leave it.  For the irony.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Enforce English grammar
string customerNm = customerNm.EndsWith("s") ? customerNm+= "'" : customerNm+="'s";
```

Comment: Thanks for the refactoring. neat

Answer (score 1):

```
//Apply genitive case
string customerNm = customerNm.EndsWith("s") ? customerNm+= "'" : customerNm+="'s";
```